# fboauth get user info

Tags: 7, users, social-network

I implemented fboauth module. It works fine and I can to link my site's account with facebook account.

I need if user logged in and his account is linked with facebook, show his picture at some block, else don't show picture or show some other picture.

Can you help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use the function `fboauth_fbid_load()` you get facebook id or FALSE.
With the facebook id you can obtain profile picture.